# AUTO SYNC with rsync

Tags: macos, mac, rsync

Hi guys that's my first post here so be cool, so I have a Mac with Rsync, and I have a VPS with Debian 8 on it, I want to do something but I don't know how. So I want to create a folder name SHARE on my Mac and if the inside of the folder is modified the same folder have to be update on the VPS.

It's Possible or not at all ? Thanks for awnsers

Answer (score 0):

Your VPS act as a **Rsync Server** for backup. You need to configure Rsync as a Server on the VPS and next you can synchronize folders with Rsync via SSH.

> ### Important:
>
> 1. Put the path of your Mac folder with / at end, that / means all files insides.
> 2. **--delete** will delete all the files on the server (destination) which doesn't exist on the Mac (source)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rsync -avzh --relative --delete -e 'ssh -p 22' /Users/youname/yourfolder/ server.tld:/destination/on/server/
```

For this you need to connect on the server with public key (ssh).

You can have a `cron job` who execute this bash script at regular interval or **create an AppleScript** who execute this bash script and add this applescript script on `Folder Action`, when you copy a file on this folder, it will be automatically synced.